# Why do I get an 'undefined' error when trying to read a JSON from an URL

Tags: javascript, json, getjson

I would appreciate it a lot if you guys could help me out with this problem.

I'm trying to read the JSON from this URL: https://aixtra.klinikum.rwth-aachen.de/rest_index.php but I only get an 'undefined' error. I'm able to read this JSON in the Google ARC Plugin and I can read other JSONs from other URLs with my code so I don't understand where the problem is.

This is my code:

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $.getJSON("https://aixtra.klinikum.rwth-aachen.de/rest_index.php", function(response) {
        $.each(response.data, function(index, d) {
          $("#print_kurse").append("Datum: " + d.TERMIN + ", Kurs: " + d.kurs + ", von: " + d.von + ", bis: " + d.bis + "</br>");
        });
      }).error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Error: " + jqXHR.responseText);
      });
    });
    </script>

    <div id="print_kurse"></div>
```

Any Ideas? Would appretiate it a lot!

Comment: Please show us the entire error please :)

Comment: I only get an alert with the following text:
Unter aixtra.rwth-aachen.de wird Folgendes angezeigt:

Error:

Sorry, the 'undefined' was in another case. Been trying it for 2 days now and tryied so many possibilities and got nothing so far

Comment: Maybe `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`?

Comment: @Paul
this is the header and echo from the page generating the url:
`header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($message, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHED);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with AJAX requests over HTTP/HTTPS. You are requesting content from an HTTPS source over HTTP. This blocked by the server you're trying to reach. Make sure you are requesting the data over HTTPS.

Comment: Has to be as the code works fine when requesting from the same Plunkr URL: (https://plnkr.co/edit/mUtLCS)

Comment: @Patrick2607
how could I do that? Is it something I would have to add to my code?

Comment: Did you develop the API yourself and do you have access to modify the code?

Comment: Now I manged to change the URL to http:// and it still doesn't work.
Yes, I developed the API, so I can change it as I need.
Why? Do you have any Ideas? By the way: the link changed a bit to: [link](http://aixtra.klinikum.rwth-aachen.de/cms/rest_index.php)

Comment: You need to activate Access-Control-Allow-Origin on your server. Read more about that subject here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work